# Transform array by cutting in half but extend elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to transform an existing array to display it. Therefore I cut the array in half but add the content of the cut element to the remained elements.

```
# source structure
s = [[1, 'blue'], 
     [2, 'red'], 
     [3, 'yellow'], 
     [4, 'green'], 
     [5, 'orange'], 
     [6, 'black']]

# result structure
format_array(s) 
# [[1, 'blue', 4, 'green'], 
#  [2, 'red', 5, 'orange'], 
#  [3, 'yellow', 6, 'black']]
```

How would you achieve it?

Comment: What do you have so far? Did you manage to cut the array in half?

Comment: @Stefan I didn't want to give a direction. I'm interested in the suggestion of the community, since the solution wasn't obvious to me. I used `each_slice`/`zip`/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.each_slice((s.size + 1) / 2).reduce(&:zip).map(&:flatten)
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it works also with odd array elements, you don't need extra variables and it uses common methods of `Array` and `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [[1, "blue"], [2, "red"], [3, "yellow"], [4, "green"], [5, "orange"], [6, "black"]]
first, last = a.first(a.size / 2), a.last(a.size / 2)
#=> [[[1, "blue"], [2, "red"], [3, "yellow"]], [[4, "green"], [5, "orange"], [6, "black"]]]
first.zip(last).map(&:flatten)
# [
#   [1, "blue", 4, "green"],
#   [2, "red", 5, "orange"],
#   [3, "yellow", 6, "black"]
# ]
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case, but using `a.first(a.size / 2)` / `a.last(a.size / 2)` to split an array in half may result in a missing middle element, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]` => `[1,2]` / `[4,5]`

Comment: @Stefan yea, was aware of it, but assumed, that array always has even number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

Just one more solution:

```
a.each_slice(a.size / 2).to_a.transpose.map(&:flatten)
#=> [[1, "blue", 4, "green"], [2, "red", 5, "orange"], [3, "yellow", 6, "black"]]
```

Comment: Neat solution using [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) here.

Answer (score 2):

**Step1:** **Divide array into two** using **`each_slice`** method of array. [each_slice documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice)

**Step2:** Use `array.zip` method to map `self with corresponding elements` of array. [zip documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/zip)

**Step3:** Use `flatten` to flatten the array. [Flatten documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/flatten)

```
s  => [[1, "blue"], [2, "red"], [3, "yellow"], [4, "green"], [5, "orange"], [6, "black"]]

s1,s2 = s.each_slice((s.length)/2).to_a

==> [[[1, "blue"], [2, "red"], [3, "yellow"]], [[4, "green"], [5, "orange"], [6, "black"]]]

s1.zip(s2).map(&:flatten)

=> [[1, "blue", 4, "green"], [2, "red", 5, "orange"], [3, "yellow", 6, "black"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [[1, 'blue'], [2, 'red'], [3, 'yellow'], [4, 'green'], [5, 'orange'], [6, 'black']]

# Split into two sections
s1 = s[0...s.length/2]
s2 = s[s.length/2..-1]

# Compile
p s1.each_with_index.map { |x, i| x + s2[i] }
#[[1, "blue", 4, "green"], [2, "red", 5, "orange"], [3, "yellow", 6, "black"]]
```

Comment: `s[0..s.length/2-1]` => `s[0...s.length/2]`

Comment: Nope. [0..x] includes x as well. 6/2 = 3 -> should be 2 (0,1,2)

Comment: It's just about the `-1`, i.e. `0..x-1` is equivalent to `0...x`

Comment: Ah i missed that extra dot, yup

Comment: It also aligns a bit nicer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

a maths trick -))

```
s.group_by {|a| a[0]%((s.length)/2) }.values.map {|e| e.flatten }
# [
#   [1, "blue", 4, "green"], 
#   [2, "red", 5, "orange"], 
#   [3, "yellow", 6, "black"]
# ]
```

Comment: `s.group_by { |n, _| n % (s.length / 2) }.values.map(&:flatten)`

Comment: yeah, that's better and cleaner -))

Comment: A solution not using the array content for grouping: `half = (a.length + 1)/2; a.group_by.with_index {|_,i| i % half }.values.map(&:flatten)`.

Comment: @sschmeck that's  also a good solution, but for my opinion adding 1 to `a.length` is is unnecessary - evens are divisible by 2 and it's ok, for odds `half` will always be the nearest small even's half (`(2k+1)/2 -> 2k/2` -> `k`).